# A diificulty in understanding a formula in Petrovic.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

Here is below: if we know that $\theta_{n}$ and $c_{n}$is defined as below

> [image]
>
> [image]

How is the two lines containing  $\theta_{n}$ below produced? I feel there is something wrong.

> [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming lemma $1.5.6$ to be correct.

Correction:

\begin{align}
\frac{\theta_n }{n!}  &= \frac{(e-c_n)n!}{n!}\\
&=  e-c_n \\
&= \frac{m}{n}-c_n
\end{align}

Now multiply $n!$ to both sides

$$\theta_n = n!\left(\frac{m}{n}-c_n \right)$$

Now by Lemma $1.5.6$, the LHS is between $0$ and $1$ but the RHS is an integer.

Remark:

Another possibility is in lemma $1.5.6$, he intended to define $\theta_n = (e-c_n)(n+1)!$. Notice that if $(e-c_n)(n+1)! \in (0,1)$ then we have  $(e-c_n)n! \in (0,1)$.

Comment: So $(n+1)!$ is a typo..?

Comment: Seems like it isn't it if the lemma is true?

Comment: Fine..........!

Comment: Another possibility is perhaps there is mitake in lemma $1.5.6$ or if I make a mistake (could be)